# What models of Sony Vaio laptops does Mark use in "The Social Network"?

Tags: the-social-network

In the scenes where Mark is on his laptop (e.g. getting the facebooks of the various houses, messing around with Apache near the end, etc.), Mark is using a Sony Vaio laptop running a KDE desktop environment. What are the specific models that he uses?

Comment: Welcome to SE. You'll need to add a photo for people to help.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Seems to be a Sony VAIO SZ (or VGN-SZ) series ultraportable notebook, introduced in 2006.

The actual model would be hard to discern as they all(around 7 of them)  looked pretty much the same externally (though lower price point versions lacked the webcam)

Since there wasn't a photo in the OP's question and I didn't fancy watching it again, I found this page, which might include images from the scene you refer to:

https://productplacementblog.com/movies/sony-vaio-notebooks-the-social-network-2010/